# Plot probability density function in Python 3d surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, surface, scipy.stats

What is the best way to plot a two-dimensional (bivariate) probability distribution (`scipy.stats.norm`) in 3d like the example surface plots below. I don't think `seaborn` comes out of the box with these, but thinking first in terms of `pyplot` or `pylab`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some similar questions are [3D Probability Density Plots in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247430/3d-probability-density-plots-in-python), [Plot normal distribution in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698277/plot-normal-distribution-in-3d) and [How to plot 3d gaussian distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622203/how-to-plot-3d-gaussian-distribution-with-matplotlib)

Comment: FYI: ["Since heavily importing into the global namespace may result in unexpected behavior, the use of pylab is strongly discouraged. Use matplotlib.pyplot instead."](https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html?highlight=pylab#module-pylab)

Comment: Without the projections of the surface's profiles on to the side panels, I would consider this post `duplicate`. ;P